# PowerPoint VBA z-order based on shape position on slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint, z-order

I would like to reorder (z-order) my 'lassoed' selection of shapes based on their position. My current macro ignores their position and the loop loops through the shapes based on their existing z-order which defeats the purpose of the loop!

For example I have 3 shapes in a grid with '1 row' and '3 columns'. When I lasso select the shapes with my mouse and run this macro, I want the left most shape to the in the front, the next shape (middle shape) to be one z-order behind, and the right most shape to then be one z-order behind of the middle shape.

Current code below:

```
Dim shp As Shape

For each shp in Activewindow.Selection.ShapeRange
shp.zorder msoBringToFront
Next
```

Comment: If you stop through a shaperange, you'll get the shapes in z-order. That's just how PPT works. If you want to order them by .Left position, you'll want to do something like add the shapes to an array, then sort them on .Left position before sending them to the z-order you want.

Comment: Actually, the changes to the macro that I thought would work doesn't work as intended. How do I loop through the shapes from left to right, top to bottom with the 'first' top left shape as the anchor even if there is a shape later in the grid that might have a .top value higher than the first 'anchor' shape?

Comment: Do you want to change the z-order for optical reasons or only because you need the "correct" order only in your macro?

Comment: Sounds like they will be animated or something, so they appear coming from below the previous one on the left.

Comment: It is for animation and also for a separate macro which aligns shapes to a grid based on user inputs which isn't working properly due to the zorder of shapes

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the main task is to sort a list of shapes by position.

The following function will sort a list of shapes and return an array of shapes in the correct order. You can call it either with a ShapeRange or with Shapes as argument: Use `ShapeRange` for selection or use `slide.Shapes` to deal with all shapes of a slide.

The function uses a simple Quicksort to sort by the position of the shapes. I use the `round`-function because the position of the shapes might be slightly different, even if you align them.

```
Function orderShapes(shapeRange) As shape()
    ' shapeRange can be either of type ShapeRange or of type Shapes
  
    If shapeRange.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
  
    ' Fill an array with all shapes.
    ReDim shapeArray(1 To shapeRange.Count) As shape
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To shapeRange.Count
        Set shapeArray(i) = shapeRange(i)
    Next
    
    ' Sort by position (left/top). 
    For i = 1 To UBound(shapeArray) - 1
        For j = i To UBound(shapeArray)
            Dim left1 As Double, left2 As Double, top1 As Double, top2 As Double
            left1 = Round(shapeArray(i).Left, 1)
            top1 = Round(shapeArray(i).Top, 1)
            left2 = Round(shapeArray(j).Left, 1)
            top2 = Round(shapeArray(j).Top, 1)
            If left1 > left2 Or (left1 = left2 And top1 > top2) Then
                ' Use this to sort from top to bottom:
                ' If top1 > top2 Or (top1 =  top2 And left1 > left2) Then
                Dim tmpShape As shape
                Set tmpShape = shapeArray(i)
                Set shapeArray(i) = shapeArray(j)
                Set shapeArray(j) = tmpShape
            End If
        Next
    Next
    
    orderShapes = shapeArray
End Function
```

Now with the resulting array you can do whatever you want. The following routine will sort the shapes of a slide and write the index as text:

```
Sub slTest()
    Dim sl As Slide
    Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Dim a() As shape
    a = orderShapes(sl.Shapes)
    ' Use this to sort only the selected shapes: 
    ' a = orderShapes(ActiveWindow.Selection.shapeRange)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        a(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "  I am shape " & i
    Next
End Sub
```

Of course, you can use it also to set the zOrder:

```
Sub setZOrderOfShapes(shapeRange)
    Dim a() As shape, i As Long
    a = orderShapes(shapeRange)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        a(i).ZOrder msoBringToFront
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you Thomas for this. I will have a look to see if this is suitable once I get a chance!

Comment: Hi Thomas, the code above works perfectly after making some changes. The zorder sub couldn't be found when i tried to run it. It was fix by chaning it to:

Sub setZOrderOfShapes()
    Dim a() As Shape, i As Long
    a = orderShapes(ActiveWindow.Selection.shapeRange)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        a(i).ZOrder msoBringToFront
    Next
End Sub

Thank you so much for youre help!

Comment: Is there a way integrate an action to align top for all shapes in each respective row? The code you provided works only if each successive shape for each row is higher than the shape immediately to the right of it? I'm thinking something like, for shapes(1 to number of shapes in each row) msoAlignTops, then iterate for the next row of shapes. Or is there an easier, more elegant way of doing that?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you wrote in your last comment. Can you provide an Image of your shapes and the wanted order?

Comment: I've responded to your question with an answer and i didn't know how to comment here with an image. Thank you, and appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thomas, in the following example. I have 6 shapes in a grid of 3x2. With their 'shape number' in the textbox as their respective z-order:

[Starting shape grid with z-order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ7Ys.png)

If i run the code as it is now (I've changed the sort logic to have top1>top2 condition first), it will sort the shapes from top to bottom such that the z-order is which isn't what I want:

[Z-order after running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAE0b.png)

Is there a way code the macro in a way that will algin the first row's shapes to top, and then second row of shapes to align top such that they look like:

[Shapes aligned top per row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMRXu.png)

The code provided works as intended in only two scenarios; shapes are already aligned top for each row (the 'top1 = top2 And left1 > left2' condition will determine the order) or if each shape in each row has a higher x position to the shape to the right, like:

[Example working arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCW5i.png)

The code you provided is intended to be used for a separate macro which aligns the selected shapes into a grid with specified number columns and spacing between each shape by the user through a userform with input boxes.

The logic I'm envisioning will be something like:

- user select shapes and runs macro
- show userform (done)
- user enters number of columns and shape spacing (done)
- **z-order sorting macro which knows how many shapes are in each row from the user form and then align top for shapes for each row respectively, then sort from top to bottom from left to right**
- run the macro which aligns the shapes into a grid with user define parameters in the user form (done)

Comment: Hi, you shouldn't put more information into an answer, SO is not a Forum - answers are meant to be *answers*. If more information is needed, edit your question and put the information there. That said: You are now asking a complete new topic and should open a *new* question for that.